# How to insert JS Code into quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Alright, my question isn't clear enough, let me explain...
This is a line code from my Javascript function:
`window.open(playerInstance.getPlaylistItem()['sources'][playerInstance.getCurrentQuality()].file+'?type=video/mp4&title=VIDEO.MP4', '_blank').blur();`
You see the "VIDEO.MP4" after "title"?
I want to replace it with javascript code instead of inputting a static name, question is:
 How can I input javascript functional code into the quotes?

**UPDATE**
How to set the second script to read innerHTML?
Because It's returning "Uncaught ReferenceError: getInfo is not defined"

Both scripts are in the same HTML page, but even so it's returning function is not defined...


1st:

```
playerInstance.on('play' && 'levelsChanged', function getInfo(){
                var filename = 'MyFileName.mp4';
                return '?type=video/mp4&title='+filename;
                });
```

2nd:

```
playerInstance.addButton(
                'icon-download.png',
                'Download', 
                function() {
window.open(playerInstance.getPlaylistItem()['sources'][playerInstance.getCurrentQuality()].file+getInfo(), '_blank').blur();}, 'download');
```

Comment: Can you show the result you would like to see? I don't quite follow you.

Comment: Can you check my update?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to open the window on the callback of 'levelsChanges'.

Then you could do something like this...

```
    playerInstance.on('levelsChanged', function(){
         window.open(playerInstance.getPlaylistItem()['sources'][playerInstance.getCurrentQuality()].file
         + playerInstance.getCurrentQuality(), '_blank').blur();
    });
```

Considering this method

playerInstance.getCurrentQuality()

returns

'?type=video/mp4&title=VIDEO.MP4'

Or u can make some minor tweaks to get the filename and concatenate with the video quality

Comment: Truly not, it makes part of a Download button, and I want to download the video file: FileName + FileQuality.mp4, considering in replace "+" with space.